# Question on how DNS works within the Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dns

I’m trying to have a basic understanding of how DNS actually work within the container. I did some research online but find limited info on this subject (e.g. only a very brief description of DNS on their networking overview page https://docs.docker.com/network/#dns-services)

Question 1: is my following understanding correct?

> To resolve a particular DNS query (whose domain is a public domain, e.g. dig [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) within the docker container, packets will flow through the following components in order: container local DSN resolver, docker DNS server on the host, host DNS server

In particular:

- Container local DNS resolver: they merely act as a forwarder, forwarding all queries to the DSN server via the docker network the current container is attached to
- Docker DNS server: it is centralized server running on the host and providing services to all containers on the same host (unless some containers are explicitly configured to use different servers). It is able to resolve the container related DNS query (e.g. when one container tries to ping another container by its name). For all other queries, this server will forward them to the host’s DNS server

Question 2: why the local DNS resolver is listening on some non-default ports?

Within the container (container: ubuntu:22.10, host: ubuntu-22.10), when I list the ports currently in use. I got the following result:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
```

```
$ netstat -tulpn 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35801        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:58113        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

It looks like the DNS resolver is not listening on port 53 but instead on some random ports > 1024.

However, when I capture the DNS query/responses, I notice that the DNS response is sent back from port 53

```
$ tcpdump -i lo port 53 or port 58113 and udp &
$ dig +short www.google.com
03:08:55.215419 IP localhost.47258 > localhost.58113: UDP, length 55
03:08:55.216852 IP localhost.53 > localhost.47258: 41084 1/0/1 A 142.251.46.228 (59)
03:08:55.307792 IP localhost.50668 > localhost.58113: UDP, length 52
03:08:55.308478 IP localhost.53 > localhost.50668: 17391*$ 1/0/1 PTR localhost. (75)
```

This looks interesting. For the DNS query, the packets are sent from port 47258 (picked up by dig) to port 58113 (the port DNS resolver is listening to). However, for the response, the packets are sent from port 53 to port 47258. I can understand that this is perfectly allowed but I’m wondering why docker creates this asymmetry? Why can’t the local DNS resolver just listens on the classic port 53 for any query?

I can understand that such setup is perfectly allowed but I’m wondering why docker has to create such asymmetry in the first place? Why can’t the local DNS resolver just listens on the classic port 53 for any query?

I know this is a long question. Really appreciate any help